# Angular/Rxjs how to subscribe to a function in a loop with different parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

How can I call a function which returns an observable (subject) in a loop (pipe -> map)? The parameters for the function are different every time.

I try to explain it with an example:

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit {

  private keyFigureSubject = new Subject();
  keyFigures$ = this.keyFigureSubject.asObservable();

  load() {
    const clients$ = of([{ id: 1, name: 'Mustermann' }, { id: 2, name: 'Hans Dampf' }, { id: 3, name: 'Pleite AG' }]);
      const result = clients$.pipe(
      flatMap((clients)=> clients),
      map(client => this.loadKeyfigures(client.id)) // this isnt working 
    );

    result.subscribe(x=>console.log(x));
  }

  loadKeyfigures(clientId: number) {

    // EDIT: This is a http call in "real life"

    const keyFigures = [];
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 1, name: 'A', value: 23});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 1, name: 'B', value: 22});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 2, name: 'A', value: 12});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'A', value: 312});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'B', value: 12333});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'C', value: 4567});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'D', value: 54});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 4, name: 'A', value: 5672});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 5, name: 'A', value: 243});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 6, name: 'A', value: 334});

    keyFigures.forEach(keyFigure =>{
      if(keyFigure.clientId === clientId){
        this.keyFigureSubject.next(keyFigure);
      }
    });
    return this.keyFigureSubject.asObservable();

  }

}
```

A the end I want a list like:

```
Client 1; Keyfigure A; 23
Client 1; Keyfigure B, 22
```

The problem seems that the `subject.next()` is called before the return `subject.asObservable()` is called. And if I subscribe to the property I can not pass parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you need is to subscribe to an inner observable for each new call to `loadKeyfigures`. To do that all you'd need to do is change `map` into `mergeMap`. There's not really a loop here. You're just turning each value in your stream into an http call.

```
load() {
  from([
    { id: 1, name: 'Mustermann' }, 
    { id: 2, name: 'Hans Dampf' }, 
    { id: 3, name: 'Pleite AG' }
  ]).pipe(
    mergeMap(client => this.loadKeyfigures(client.id))
  ).subscribe(console.log);
}
```

Also, it's worth noting that your virtual http call won't work. Subjects are "hot" observables, so by the time you return it as an observable, it won't be emitting values anymore.

Try this instead:

```
loadKeyfigures(clientId: number) {

  // EDIT: This is a http call in "real life"

  const keyFigures = [];
  keyFigures.push({clientId: 1, name: 'A', value: 23});
  keyFigures.push({clientId: 1, name: 'B', value: 22});
  keyFigures.push({clientId: 2, name: 'A', value: 12});
  keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'A', value: 312});
  keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'B', value: 12333});
  keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'C', value: 4567});
  keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'D', value: 54});
  keyFigures.push({clientId: 4, name: 'A', value: 5672});
  keyFigures.push({clientId: 5, name: 'A', value: 243});
  keyFigures.push({clientId: 6, name: 'A', value: 334});

  // Use from to convert array to a stream
  return from(keyFigures.filter(fig => 
    fig.clientId === clientId
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the combination of [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) and [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap):

```
import { forkJoin } from "rxjs";
import { switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

...
switchMap(client => forkJoin(this.loadKeyfigures(client.id)))
```

In the subscription method you would then receive the list of the emitted values from each observable.

For your specific case however I don't see, why you need to return Observables from your method `loadKeyfigures`. You could also just return the value synchronously.

```
loadKeyfigures(clientId: number) {
    const keyFigures = [];
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 1, name: 'A', value: 23});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 1, name: 'B', value: 22});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 2, name: 'A', value: 12});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'A', value: 312});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'B', value: 12333});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'C', value: 4567});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 3, name: 'D', value: 54});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 4, name: 'A', value: 5672});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 5, name: 'A', value: 243});
    keyFigures.push({clientId: 6, name: 'A', value: 334});

    // Just filter out the invalid keyFigures by comparing the ids.
    return this.keyFigures.filter(({clientId: id}) => id === clientId);
  }
```

Then you could just the map operator as in your example.

Comment: Thx for your reply.
Sorry i described it wrong. The function does a http get call. I wanted to simulate the http call with the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a BehaviorSubject for simulation purposes, just use `of`

```
keyFigures.forEach(keyFigure =>{
      if(keyFigure.clientId === clientId){
        return of(keyFigure);
      }
    });
```

Please also note, that you will need a higher order operator like `switchMap` in order to switch to another observables value(s).

```
switchMap(client => this.loadKeyfigures(client.id))
```